# Remove cached software update in macOS App Store

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

How can I remove cached software update in macOS?

I assume downloaded files are corrupted (after restart the software update is stuck for hours), and would like to re-download it again.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
cd $TMPDIR/../C/com.apple.appstore
rm -rf *
```

You can also try to download update from here:

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1941?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

And re-run it.

Comment: You can try to download it directly from support page.

Comment: It also didn't help. I have left the installation for a night and it didn't move a little.

Comment: One think I have noticed is that installation time seems to depend on number of files you have. E.g. once I tried to apply patches to installation with LaTeX Live and it was taking enormous amount of time (almost forever). It's also a good idea to run HD diagnostic before starting update: Utilities -> Disk Utility -> Run First Aid...

Comment: On BigSur '$TMPDIR/../C/com.apple.appstore' does not exist; '$TMPDIR/../C/com.apple.appstoreagent' does