# Verifying "Xcode" on every macOS boot

Tags: xcode, macos, verify, macos-catalina

every time I start or restart my MacBook, macOS verifies Xcode.
[image]

This is not a picture from me I took it from another post but its basically the same just with "Xcode" (the app) instead of the image file.

It takes a while and for the time macOS is verifying Xcode the fan of the MacBook goes like to 100%. While its verifying I can't really use other applications because they freeze and will unfreeze when the verification is finished.

I tried to remove the quarantine xattr from the Xcode.app and recursively from all package components but there never was one set `xattr: /Applications/Xcode.app/: No such xattr`

I also tried to to reinstall Xcode. When booting into safe mode the same verification window appears.

This happened after I updated my mac to macOS Catalina. If you have any idea what I can try next, let me know.

Comment: If xcode is already installed, remove the .dmg, that's all.

Comment: You may have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47509324/remove-cached-software-update-in-macos-app-store

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès there is no dmg. I installed it from the app store. As I said in the post it verifies "Xcode" and not an image like "Xcode.dmg". And removing the cached files unfortunately didn't help.

Comment: Oh! Didn't read everything... Sorry. Seems that this is a recurrent problem without actual solution. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371967/macos-catalina-verifying-app-at-bootstrap. But you may ask and search directly on apple.SE.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so apparently in my case there was something messed up with my system. I couldn't find any solution and besides the Xcode problem Reminders always wanted to access a keychain of mine. Not the login, the system or iCloud Keychain but a keychain I created myself just to store and organise some password. And when I clicked on "Deny" Reminders would ask again so I only could close this window and be able to do other things when I allow access.

Anyway after I completely reinstalled macOS (first erase the whole Macintosh HD and then reinstall Catalina) everything works fine.

So if any of you doesn't have that much of data on their Mac just a few files to back up I'd definitely try a reinstall. Took my 3-4 hours and now it works again.